# Merge two XML files using Notepad++ into a third one

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two XML files that I need to combine into a third one using XSLT 1.0 only

File one:

```
<customer>
    <prefix>Mrs</prefix>
    <lastName>Macauley</lastName>
    <givenName>Ernestine</givenName>
    <addressID>547053</addressID>
    <customerID>OS2M5PKJ</customerID>
</customer>
```

File Two:

```
<transaction>
    <transaction_date>02/11/2019</transaction_date>
    <customerID>OS2M5PKJ</customerID>
    <giftShop>3</giftShop>
    <transactionID>UWMWF82vkYvh5dMQ</transactionID>
    <value currency="gbp">63.97</value>
</transaction>
```

The end result should be outputted into a third file called output.xml
and should look something like this

```
<transaction>
    <transaction_date>02/11/2019</transaction_date>
    <customerID>OS2M5PKJ</customerID>
    <giftShop>3</giftShop>
    <transactionID>UWMWF82vkYvh5dMQ</transactionID>
    <value currency="gbp">63.97</value>
    <prefix>Mrs</prefix>
    <lastName>Macauley</lastName>
    <givenName>Ernestine</givenName>
    <addressID>547053</addressID>
</transaction>
```

I am applying the XSLT to the second file using Notepad++ have tried to use `<xsl:value-of select="document('retail_transactions.xml')/*"/>` to try and read the second file but it doesn't do anything

EDIT XSLT ADDED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:copy-of select="document('C:\Users<FULL-PATH>\retail_transactions.xml')/transaction/*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Well, you should be using `<xsl:copy-of select="document('retail_transactions.xml')/transaction/*"/>`. But if your attempt did not return anything, then the file is not where you think it is. Or has a different name. Or maybe some other flaw we cannot see because you did not post the actual XSLT.

Comment: I am trying to make the XSLT and it relatively empty as i am just trying to read the entire file and I have edited to add the XSLT

Comment: What do you get with `<xsl:copy-of select="document('file:///C:/Users/full/path/to/retail_transactions.xml')"/>`? Note the use of forward slashes.

Comment: Tried / and \ variants also tried using directories that do not have spaces in the names still doesn't show anything 
the code I was using :
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:copy-of select="document('file://C:/Users/valer/Desktop/retail_transactions.xml')/*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: You are missing a slash after `file:`

Comment: I tried // and /// nothing works

Comment: Try putting the file next to the XSLT file and then `<xsl:copy-of select="document('retail_transactions.xml')"/>`. If that doesn't work (and the file name is correct) there may be a limitation in your processor.

Comment: that was one of the things i have tried and it didn't work, could it be something with the Notepad++ XML plugin ?

Comment: It could well be. Are you able to try with another application?

Comment: I don't know which one will be the best option but i am trying Eclipse at the moment, do you have any recommendations ?

Comment: I am not a Windows user. I believe Microsoft offer some kind of IDE (Visual Studio?) that allows performing XSLT on their own processor.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Mac ?and what app

Comment: I  am afraid the answer will not help you. I use several processors in macOS - and I call them from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was solved by using a different IDE (**Oxygen XML**). I have tried **VS/VS code**, but they weren't really easy to use and **Oxygen XML** seems fairly intuitive. My initial code works .

Comment: Good to hear that the issue is resolved. Out of curiosity, what XSLT engine you used in the Oxygen scenario?

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0 and the default Engine  was set as Saxon 6.5.5

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following.

You would need to adjust a fully qualified path to the XML file starting with the drive.

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('e:\<fully qualified path>\retail_transactions.xml')/transaction/*"/>
```

Comment: tried this 
```
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('C:\Users\<FullPath 
    >\retail_transactions.xml')/transactions/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
``` 
and it made a blank file

Comment: Shouldn't it be **transaction** singular instead of the *transactions* plural?

Comment: The root node is called transactions and each child node it's called transaction

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Your assertion that a fully qualified (i.e. an absolute) path is required is entirely baseless. The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#document) states explicitly that the URI reference may be relative. Moreover, the path you suggest cannot possibly work because it's a Windows path, not a URI.  You may have a friend or a fake account to offsett my downvote, but the fact remains that this is an exceptionally bad answer.